# Active tab not highlighting

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winterbash

It also doesn't highlight on mouseover.

[image]

**EDIT**: Forgot important information. This is Firefox 3.6 on Windows Vista. I tried clearing my cache. I could not reproduce on Chrome.

Comment: Reproduced in SeaMonkey 2.5 on Win 7

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 8.0 on Win 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in the next build. We were using the non-standard `background-position-y` CSS property, which unfortunately isn't supported by Firefox and Opera .